# LESS Mixins with Optional Parameters - Skip Undefined Properties

Tags: css, less, mixins

I am new to Less and trying to convert some SCSS mixins over. However, I am having some problems with optional parameters. For example:

```css
.border(@border; @block: null; @blockEnd: null) {
  border: @border;
  border-block-end: if(@blockEnd, @blockEnd, @block);
}

.container {
  .border(@border: 1px solid red);
}
```

This results in the following CSS:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-block-end: ;
}
```

Notice that `border-block-end` is still generated, but with an empty value.

How can I set mixin parameters to optional, as in `undefined` and only generate the CSS property if that parameter exists?

**Target Output**

```css
// LESS
.container {
  .border(@border: 1px solid red);
}

// Would generate CSS...
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  // Only generates properties with a value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I am able to leverage the [Mixin Guards](https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixin-guards-feature). By using the `when not` and `if not` operators nested inside the mixin, I can check for multiple parameters where the `,` separator acts as an `or`.

> When @blockEnd or @block are truthy, compile the following

```css
.border(@border; @block: null; @blockEnd: null;) {
  border: @border;
  
  & when not(@blockEnd = null), not(@block = null) {
    border-block-end: if(not (@blockEnd = null), @blockEnd, @block);
  }
}
```

This will evaluate to:

```css
// LESS
.container {
  .border(@border: 1px solid red);
}

// CSS
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

It feels quite verbose, but it gets the job done.. Am I missing an easier approach, possibly?